# /usr/bin/ld cannot find -lgraph

Tags: c++, installation

Someone send me a program to convert XCSP3 files to DIMACS SAT file, but when I try to build it I have this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgraph
```

how can I fix it please.

Comment: Make sure you have a file `libgraph.so` on your system (if on Linux) and specify the path to the linker via argument `-L/path/to/file`.

Comment: Install the missing library (some distributions split libs into runtime and development packages, you'll want both).

Comment: Maybe you can try this.
[How do I use graphics.h in Ubuntu ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu)